# How to Integrate current form into MDI form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, mdi

Im trying to open files using OpenFileDialog regardless of the amount of files opened. FileStream object needs to be used. For the most part I think I figured that out..  Currently trying to figure out the MDI Child form property stuff. Moreover, Im trying to be able to transition that into my current project. I want to be able to open as many files as I want by selecting mnuFutureValue, then typing in them and saving those files.  This is the text editor I've already created.

```
Dim filePathway As String = UNTITLED_FILE
Private Const UNTITLED_FILE As String = "Untitled"
Dim fileContentContainer As String = String.Empty
Dim isFileTerminated As Boolean = False


Private Sub mnuOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuOpen.Click

    HasChanged()

    If isFileTerminated <> True Then
        Me.Text = "Untitled"
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"

        If openFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                filePathway = openFileDialog.FileName
                Dim fileStream As New FileStream(filePathway, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                Dim readStream As New StreamReader(fileStream)

                txtTextEditer.Text = readStream.ReadToEnd()
                fileContentContainer = txtTextEditer.Text
                CurrentFileName()
                openFileDialog.FileName = String.Empty
                readStream.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            CurrentFileName()
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub mnuSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuSave.Click
    Me.Text = "Save File "
    If filePathway = UNTITLED_FILE Then
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"
        If saveFileDialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                filePathway = saveFileDialog.FileName
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            CurrentFileName()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    FileSaver(filePathway)
    CurrentFileName()
End Sub


Private Sub mnuSaveAs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuSaveAs.Click
    Me.Text = "Save File As"
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            filePathway = saveFileDialog.FileName
            FileSaver(filePathway)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
    CurrentFileName()
End Sub


Private Sub mnuNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuNew.Click
    HasChanged()
    If isFileTerminated <> True Then
        txtTextEditer.Text = String.Empty
        fileContentContainer = txtTextEditer.Text
        filePathway = UNTITLED_FILE
        CurrentFileName()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HasChanged()
    isFileTerminated = False
    If txtTextEditer.Text <> fileContentContainer Then
        Dim msgBoxResult = MsgBox("Unsaved changes will be lost. Would you like to save your " & filePathway.ToString() & " document and exit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Warning!")
        If msgBoxResult = DialogResult.Yes Then
            mnuSave.PerformClick()
        ElseIf msgBoxResult = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            isFileTerminated = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FileSaver(path As String)

    Dim fileStream As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim writeStream As New StreamWriter(fileStream)


    writeStream.Write(txtTextEditer.Text)
    writeStream.Close()


    saveFileDialog.FileName = String.Empty
    fileContentContainer = txtTextEditer.Text
End Sub


Private Sub CurrentFileName()
    Me.Text = Path.GetFileName(filePathway) & " - Text Editer"
End Sub


Private Sub mnuCut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuCut.Click
    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(txtTextEditer.SelectedText)
    txtTextEditer.SelectedText() = String.Empty
End Sub


Private Sub mnuCopy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuCopy.Click
    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(txtTextEditer.SelectedText)
End Sub


Private Sub mnuPaste_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuPaster.Click
    txtTextEditer.SelectedText() = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()
End Sub


Private Sub mnuExit_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuExit.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub

Private Sub frmTextEditor_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = True
    HasChanged()
    If isFileTerminated <> True Then
        e.Cancel = False
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub mnuAbout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuAbout.Click
    MsgBox("" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "")
End Sub


Private Sub frmTextEditor_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CurrentFileName()
End Sub


Private Sub mnuClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub mnuNewFutureValue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuNewFutureValue.Click
    Dim futureValueForm As New ChildForm
    futureValueForm.MdiParent = Me
    futureValueForm.Show()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Please read the description of each tag carefully. The VBA tag explicitly states that it is a different language to VB.NET and should not be used for questions relating to VB.NET. The VS tag explicitly states it is for IDE issues and not questions on code written in VS.

Comment: There's way too much code there. You need to narrow the question down and provide ONLY the relevant code. If we have to wade through mountains of irrelevant code, we may not find the relevant code or even bother to try to find it, which is bad for you.

Answer (score 0):

You would have the functionality to select the file in the MDI parent form. You could put the functionality to open and read the file in the child form, in which case you could just pass the file path to that form, e.g.

```vb
Public Class ChildForm

    Private filePath As String

    Public Sub New(filePath As String)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        Me.filePath = filePath
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChildForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath)
    End Sub

End Class
```

In that parent form, you would then do this:

```vb
Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim mdiChild As New ChildForm(ofd.FileName)

        mdiChild.MdiParent = Me
        mdiChild.Show()
    End If
End Using
```

Alternatively, the code to read the file could be in the parent and the child just takes the data, e.g.

```vb
Public Class ChildForm

    Public Property Data As String
        Get
            Return TextBox1.Text
        End Get
        Set
            TextBox1.Text = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

and

```vb
Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim mdiChild As New ChildForm

        mdiChild.Data = IO.File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName)
        mdiChild.MdiParent = Me
        mdiChild.Show()
    End If
End Using
```

Either way, that allows you to open and display as many different files as you want. Just note that, if you haven't already, you need to set `IsMdiContainer` to `True` on the parent form.